# ReactJs: useState making string empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// App.js

const [currentContent, setCurrentContent] = useState('')

const openNote = (id) => {
    notes.forEach(note => note.id == id && setCurrentContent(note.content))
}
```

Part of return:

```
<TextRegion className="center" content={currentContent}/>
```

I am passing content as a prop via a state seen in the code block above. This seems to work fine.

```
// TextRegion.js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const TextRegion = ({ content  }) => {
    const [areaText, setAreaText] = useState(content)
    console.log(areaText)
    return (
        <div className="form-div">
            <form className="form">
                <textarea className="content form-control" type="text" value={content}/>
                 <button style={{'float': 'right'}} className="btn btn-primary mt-2 mr-2" type='submit'>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TextRegion;
```

The issue arises when I attempt to set the content prop to the default state of areaText. Content is of type string, and prints to console just fine. Although, when trying to print areaText, an empty string is returned. This is baffling to me, any explanations? Thanks.

Comment: You should print the value when it is a Truthy value. Just check if it is Truthy then only print the value.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem is the value is never Truthy, The state is always empty even if content is a valid string.

Comment: Actually it is Falsy first as it is an empty string but once the state gets updated it becomes Truthy. So it logs an empty string as you did not specify what condition it should be logged on. `if (areaText) {console.log(areaText)}` should work.

Comment: Yeah, it's not printing anything. Super weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value for `useState` is used once when the component is mounted. In your `TextRegion` component, `areaText` is set to the value of the `content` prop when `TextRegion` is mounted. Since `currentContent` is initialised as an empty string, so is `areaText`.

If you change the value of `content` prop while the `TextRegion` is mounted, the `useState` hook controlling `areaText` will just ignore the new value, because it has already initialised the value for `areaText`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks. How would I go about updating the value?

Comment: It's probably best to review the concepts of "lifting state up". (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and "controlled components" (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). You seem to be trying to store the textarea's value in two places at the moment. The `useState` hook in the `TextRegion` appears to be redundant, as you are passing in the textarea's value as a prop.

Comment: Great thinking. I ended up removing the state in TextRegion and just passing down the state and update state from the top level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One issue I found is in your `textRegion.js` you are using form and the button is type of submit so that will reload your page. always use e.preventDefault on submit method in react applications.

You can pass both currentContent and setCurrentContent via pros and use that state directly rather than creating a new state.

Use two way binding in react.

Example

```
<textarea 
  className="content form-control" type="text" 
  value={areaText} 
  onChage={(e)=> setAreaText(e.target.value)} 
/>
```